# Les patois et le français

Tags: régionalismes

Concernant les différents [patois](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langues_r%C3%A9gionales_de_France)¹, quelle est aujourd'hui leur force de pénétration dans la langue française ?

*Aucune langue régionale ou minoritaire n'a de statut de langue officielle en France.*
Cependant, certains patois parviennent-ils à "imposer" certains de leurs mots dans la langue française et à les faire rentrer dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie ? Cette transition d'un mot de patois vers une langue officielle a-t-elle d'ailleurs un nom ?

¹ A prendre de manière non péjorative, j'aime ce mot et particulièrement le mien (nissard)

Comment: de l'influence bien sûr, maintenant est-ce qu'elles en ont encore? Peut-être des expressions continuent de se répandre ponctuellement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Le statut de la langue française (et des parlers dit "régionaux") est avant tout un problème politique en France. Depuis à peu près 5 siècles, la nation française se définit principalement sur une unité de territoire *et* de langue. Néanmoins, d'un point de vue linguistique, la hiérarchisation des langues historiques du territoire français est tout à fait arbitraire.

Pour ta question: tout dépend de ta définition de "patois" (et il y a des volumes entiers à écrire).

Je soupçonne la plupart des exemples couramment cités de "patois" (ceux qui sont encore répandus) d'être en fait des langues à part entière (breton, basque etc.).

Le tien (nissard) n'est autre qu'un descendant presque direct de l'occitan, qui était à la fois concurrent et ancêtre du français moderne. Donc, intrinsèquement, le français moderne (latin passé à la moulinette de l'occitan, langue d'oïl et probablement bien d'autres dialectes régionaux) *est déjà* un mélange de "patois" tels que le nissard.

Quant à une influence contemporaine: peu probable, je dirais, sachant que très peu de gens en dessous d'un certain âge parlent encore des dialectes régionaux (et les retraités sont rarement des vecteurs de dynamisme de la langue ;-).

Comment: "Je suspecte"? C'est moi ou c'est un peu suspect?

Comment: @Benjol: tu as raison... je crois qu'il s'agit d'un anglicisme (plus ou moins passé dans la langue courante, non?). J'ai corrigé pour une tournure plus idiomatique.

Comment: Dave, je suspectais que c'était un anglicisme :) Que ce soit passé dans la langue courante je n'en sais rien : comme avec l'orthographe, plus je regardes, moins je suis sûr :)

Comment: C'est moins loufoque que _je suppute_ ou _je subodore_.

Comment: @Joubarc: *suppute* ou *subodore* sont un peu précieux, mais parfaitement idiomatique... *suspecte* (dans ce contexte) a en effet un fort relent de gigot mentholé. Je ne suis hélas pas en mesure de dire si le terme est acceptable (ou au moins courant) dans le français de tous les jours.

Comment: Si suspecter est un anglicisme - ce dont je doute, pourquoi le serait-il ? - il est attesté en français depuis le XVIe siècle (source TLF).

Comment: @François: "suspecter" tout seul ne l'est pas. L'usage "Je suspecte [qu'il s'agit d'une erreur]" etc. l'est probablement. C'est comme l'usage de "réaliser" pour "comprendre" (qui est un anglicisme tellement courant qu'il est en passe de devenir normal).

Answer (score 7):

À part les langues régionales comme le basque, le corse, le breton et peut-être l'alsacien (je ne connais pas suffisamment cette région) qui disposent de leurs propres écoles et de leurs propres panneaux de signalisation par exemple, les patois français survivent pour la plupart plus sous la forme de mots isolés. Mon grand-père parle un peu le patois (ça donne des phrases comme « O lé de la bonne gâche do père Gâtard » => « C'est de la bonne brioche du Père Gâtard »), mais mes parents ne le parlent pas du tout. Quant à ma génération (20-30 ans), je crains que ce ne soit plus qu'un motif de blague...

Je viens de l'Ouest (Poitou-Charentes/Vendée) et j'emploie des termes comme « poche » pour « sac - souvent en plastique - fourni dans les magasins », « chocolatine » pour « pain au chocolat », « tantôt » pour « après-midi » et « débaucher » pour "quitter le travail le soir », « sinser » pour « serpiller », « barrer » pour « fermer une porte à clé ».
Il y a bien d'autres mots qui ainsi passent petit à petit d'un patois ou d'une langue régionale dans le « français » officiel au fil des déplacements des gens (surtout les jeunes, avec la mobilité liée aux études ou au travail).

Par contre, en tant que jeune provinciale émigrée sur Paris, je peux dire que je reçois parfois quelques moqueries quand j'emploie les mots de mon patois :)
Ca peut donner envie d'arrêter, mais c'est tellement joli, « chocolatine » :)

Comment: « Votre chocolatine, je vous la mets dans une poche ? » — j'adore !

Comment: c'est du "patois" chocolatine ou poche? Ca vient d'une langue régionale ou c'est plutôt une expression locale? Sinon l'Occitan, dans tout le sud, a quand même des écoles et panneaux etc... Pour moi il y a bien des expressions que j'entends dans le sud qui viennent directement de l'occitan ( s'enfader, avoir la niaque, adiou ... ) mais "chocolatine" ou "poche" je dirais pas que ça vient de l'occitan...

Comment: [À propos de la chocolatine…](http://blog.adrienvh.fr/2012/10/16/cartographie-des-resultats-de-chocolatine-ou-pain-au-chocolat/)

Answer (score 6):

L'occitan a donné le fameux *kézako* qui s'écrit « Qu'es aquò ». Il y a aussi *cramer* pour *brûler* ou la *castagne* popularisée par Claude Nougaro.

Le Wiktionnaire en a [toute une liste](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie%3afran%C3%A7ais_d%E2%80%99Occitanie).

Answer (score 2):

L'Alsacien a offert quelques mots au Français familier, l'Académie n'en a à ce jour pas voulu :

- Le "Schluck" : la gorgée
- Le "Stück" : un (beau) morceau : une fille canon, un homme bien bâti...
- Être Schlass : être ivre.
- Être "Fràch" ou "Frech" : être effronté
- Le "Schnock" (avec un "o" court) : l'être sénile, en général "le vieux Schnock"

[Wikipedia a quelques autres exemples](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_d%27Alsace#Emprunts_.C3.A0_l.27alsacien).

Comment: A part Schnock, toutes inconnues pour moi dans le sud de la France

Comment: Inconnus aussi dans le Nord de la France ^^.
Vis-à-vis du sujet, il me semble que le Picard (car je viens de Picardie) a influencé de manière importante la langue française au début (la Picardie étant près de Paris), mais ce n'est plus du tout le cas, d'autant que peu de personnes le parlent maintenant.

Answer (score 2):

Pour le pénétration du breton dans la langue française, je conseille ce petit livre : [Les Bretonnismes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2915623732)

Il explique les expressions et tournures françaises qui viennent du breton (expressions majoritairement utilisées en Bretagne)